# Can I use Xcode to run previously purchased apps?

Tags: applications, xcode

So I bought an app from the app store and I'd like to run it in Xcode. I know you can hook up your Apple ID to Xcode but I wasn't sure if you can then download previously purchased apps and run them. Anyone know?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by running them in Xcode? Debugging them? Using Instruments?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run bought apps in the iOS simulator in Xcode.